# Omit Na values in a Chi Squared test

Tags: r, na, missing-data, chi-squared

I needed a function for get the p-values of multiple Chi-Square tests in a Matrix
Looking for, I found this code:

```
chisqmatrix <- function(x) {
  names = colnames(x);  num = length(names)
  m = matrix(nrow=num,ncol=num,dimnames=list(names,names))
  for (i in 1:(num-1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):num) {
      m[i,j] = chisq.test(x[,i],x[,j],)$p.value
    }
  }
  return (m)
}
mat = chisqmatrix(DATAFRAME)
mat
```

And works perfectly!

but the problem is that I need that this function omit the NA values.

I can't just omit the NA values in all the dataframe, I need them to be omitted for each pair in the function

So when `x[,i]`  select the columns How can I implement that for only take the values that are not null. I tried things like !="NA" but not correctly way.

Thanks you!

Comment: just to check, do you mean to do chisq.test(x[,i],x[,j],) or chisq.test(cbind(x[,i],x[,j],))

Comment: If both are vectors, then according to the vignette "cases with missing values are removed,the objects are coerced to factors, and the contingency table is computed from these", meaning, you don't need to remove NAs. But it is really weird if this is intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to provide reproducible data. As documented on the manual page, `chisq.test` removes missing values before computing:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- matrix(sample(c(LETTERS[1:3], NA), 100, replace=TRUE), 20, 5)
x <- data.frame(x)
head(x)
#     X1   X2   X3 X4   X5
# 1    A    C    C  A <NA>
# 2    A    C    C  B    A
# 3    A    A    B  B    B
# 4    A    A    B  B    A
# 5    B    C <NA>  B    A
# 6 <NA> <NA> <NA>  B <NA>
x.chi <- chisq.test(x[, 1], x[, 2])
# Warning message:
# In chisq.test(x[, 1], x[, 2]) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
x.chi$observed
#       x[, 2]
# x[, 1] A B C
#      A 3 1 3
#      B 2 1 2
sum(x.chi$observed) # How many observations in x.chi?
[1] 12
nrow(na.omit(x[, 1:2])) $ How many rows in x after removing NAs?
[1] 12
```

Your function will do exactly what you want it to do.